# Android Animation to be done from bottom towards up but will be invisible in center

Tags: android, android-animation

http://framerjs.com/examples/preview/#carousel-onboarding.framer like this i have to develop,please check this link only on Chrome .

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is an Animation Resource File (a file in the res>anim directory of your project. If you don't have the anim directory you can simply create it.).

The content of this file (named as you wish, like `myanimation.xml`) should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-50" />

</set>
```

The  tag means that the object will animate from completely opaque (1.0) to completly trasparent (0.0)

The  tag means that the object will animate from its starting position to the same X coordinate and 50 pixels above.

To use this animation from an Activity simply use:

```
Animation myAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanimation); 
myAnimation.setDuration(millisecYouWant);
viewIWantToAnimate.startAnimation(myAnimation);
```

for more complex animations look at this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

EDIT: I think the question should have more details, in this case something like the piece of code where you want to applicate this animation, or what you want to animate (like an ImageView, or a Layout ...)

Comment: I want to animate a imageview from bottom to center like in the link its animating .